# How can I stop Vaadin from triggering my window's ParameterHandler more than necessary?

Tags: vaadin

I added a ParameterHandler to my application's main window so I can catch and process custom get parameters in my url. However, the presence of one parameter reloads the first page of my application, for some reason building this page triggers the handleParameters method again, this time with no parameters passed. If left unchecked (e.g. no ifs) the page's elements will just replicate themselves on top of themselves over and over again.

I suspect it has something to do with my main windows's addComponent method.

How can I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely forgot I still had this question open. I found that the problem was that the method got triggered for both get and post type parameters, and this is what caused the unexpected output.

I already implemented an HttpServletRequestListener because I used Vaadin's [ThreadLocal pattern](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ThreadLocal%20Pattern), so I just filtered all GET parameters out of the request object in one of the implemented methods and went from there.

Answer (score 0):

debug your application and have a view at the call stack of the handleParameters method